# Bad input C vs C++ cin vs scanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf, cin

Im a total beginner in C and here is my problem. In C++ I would look for bad input(not unsigned int) this way:

```
long double c;
cin >> c;

if (c == (unsigned int) c) {
cout<<"OK";    
}
else
cout<<"NOT OK";
```

However when now learning C I'm trying to do it the same way, but it does not work:

```
long double c;
scanf("%lf", &c);

if (c == (unsigned int) c) {
printf("OK\n");    
}
else
printf("NOT OK\n");
```

Any advice on how to fix it? My task is to do this by just using scanf and no strings. I don't want negative and float numbers to be inputted. Why doesnt this work?

Comment: Why are you scanning into a `long double` when you want your input to be `unsigned int`?

Comment: @Xymostech *"I need check for negative and float numbers."*

Comment: Im scanning for double so that when I compare (c == (unsigned int) c), here c would still be floating point and not converted to an integer. This way I can check whether the input number was for example "1.2" instead of just "1".

Answer (score 4):

The conversion directive `%lf` is for scanning `double`s.

To scan `long double`s, use `%Lf`, with an upper case `L`.

From the specification of `fscanf` (7.21.6.2)

> **l** (ell)  Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, X, or n conversion specifier applies
>   to an argument with type pointer to `long int` or `unsigned long int`; **that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `double`**; or that a following c, s, or [ conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `wchar_t`.
>
> **L** Specifies that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `long double`.

Comment: isn't L for long long and l for long ? It still doesnt work. Ty

Comment: @user2211796 No, for `long long`, you use `%lld` (or `%lli`) with the `ll` length modifier.

Comment: @user2211796 With "it still doesn't work", what exactly do you mean, in how far does it not work?

Comment: For example if I printf("%Lf", c) in C; it shows 2.00000000 and it go to NOT OK; If I cout c in C++. It shows 2 and goes to OK;

Comment: The input was 2 in both C and C++. In C++ it works, in C it doesnt

Comment: That would be extremely odd (works here by the way, but that doesn't help you). Can you `printf("%.25LF\n",c);` with more digits? An input of just 2 ought to be properly converted as `float`, `double`, and `long double`. I'd be curious to know what it was converted to for you. Also, what compiler, what OS?

Comment: printf("%.25LF\n",c); prints nothing, u probably meant printf("%.25Lf\n",c). It prints 2.0000000000000000 with only zeroes Dev-C++ with GCC and win7 :)

Comment: @user2211796 Yes, I meant `%.25Lf`, but that shouldn't matter, `F` is a valid conversion too. So the value is exactly 2 (hmm, or `long double` has even more precision on your system, try `%.50Lf`?), but yet it claims `c != (unsigned int)c`? What gcc version is your Dev-C++ using?

Comment: the printf works fine. I can try even %.1000000Lf and it shows a lot of zeroes :) gcc 3.4.2 Edit: Btw, just tried to make c double instead of long double and now c == (unsigned int) c works. It still prints 2.000000... but it works :)

Comment: 3.4.2, talk about ancient. Nevertheless, it should work, gcc had proper `long double` support at that time (at least on Linux, maybe not on Windows?). Does it work if you change the type of `c` to `double` (and the formats to `%lf` then)?